# C# how to get a bitmap from a picturebox

Tags: c#, bitmap, picturebox, bitmapimage

I have a image in picturebox. I want to get that image as a Bitmap.

My one line code is:

`Bitmap default_image = (Bitmap)pictureBox5.Image.Clone();`

But what i am getting is:

`default_image value=null;`

Can anyone help me.

Answer (score 19):

```
Bitmap default_image = new Bitmap(pictureBox5.Image);
```

You are never instantiating a `Bitmap` which is why it is `null`.

Comment: If he's getting null out of Image.Clone(), then calling the constructor with the same image property isn't going to do very much either.

Comment: @MGZero: It is my understanding that it is null because you cannot cast a Image object to a Bitmap.

Comment: Bitmap is inherited from Image..sooo...yes, you are correct.  +1 now that I'm certain :)

Answer (score 2):

If you got the image into the PictureBox by using imageLocation

```
pbSourceImage.ImageLocation = openFile.FileName;
```

then PictureBox.Image will be null.

Instead, load the picture using

```
pbSourceImage.Image = Image.FromFile(openFile.FileName);
```

Then you will be able to clone from the Image property.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you do not have image, probably you have **BackgroundImage**.
You need to have **Image** properties fill with your picture.