# How to get name of the image

Tags: c#, .net, image, image-processing

I am using Aforge.net samples and i wanted to get name of the images which are placed on resources. I am unable to do so as image.tag is givng an error.

Please help

Comment: try this http://forums.asp.net/t/1774226.aspx/1

Comment: @Sherlock you can't help. We need psychic here, not detective;)

Comment: I have an image named stop.png. I have loaded this image into resourceBitmap img1 = new Bitmap(Properties.Resources.Stop); i wanted to get name of the image i.e i wanted to get stop does this make any sense?

Comment: @user2174920 its impossible to achive that you are asking about. `Bitmap` class have inside only image binary data and knows nothing about the place from which this data was loaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can using the Uri Class to load the path and pull the Image name from Segments collection:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://www.XXXX.com/imageName.jpg");
string fileName = uri.Segments.Last();
```

Edit

Let see this answers: if you like it ?

[C# how to get a bitmap from a picturebox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996987/c-sharp-how-to-get-a-bitmap-from-a-picturebox)

[Get bitmap file name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10054136/c-sharp-get-bitmap-file-name)

New Edit

```
System.IO.FileInfo info = new System.IO.FileInfo(Properties.Resources.Stop);
string fileName = info.Name;
```

Comment: I have an image named stop.png. I have loaded this image into resourceBitmap img1 = new Bitmap(Properties.Resources.Stop); i wanted to get name of the image i.e  i wanted to get stop does this make any sense?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The links which you have given above shows how to change names of image files. I wanted to display the names of image file in a textbox or label

Comment: You get no help from Bitmap, it doesn't keep track of a file name. Nor does a Bitmap have to be created from a file, it has several constructors. You'll need to keep track of this yourself with a string variable.

Comment: is there any way to get name of image file and display it in textbox?